# c# proxy ssl / tls passthrough without certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, https, proxy, tls1.2

This is the issue.

I have an https request. The request is is being sent as an SSL / TLS request (Not the CONNECT .... that comes from a browser with the proxy setup).

I need to write a proxy in c# that blocks a specific https://foo.com/foo.htm request but lets through https://foo.com/anything_else.htm.

I can do this fine creating a MITM attack with a new certificate etc etc.

But Im now wondering if there is an easy way to do this Im missing without using a MITM attack as I have no need to decrypt the data. I only need to know the URI/file.

I can easily just transfer streams but I want to know if there is a simple way to transfer the streams after I have read the URI and file.

I can write some fancy code to pull apart the tcp request and thats what I may have to do.

Anybody any ideas before I go down this path. Remember there is no CONNECT request. Just direct SSL / TLS.

The main reason for this is it just makes things simpler not creating self signed certificates etc.

Maybe its even possible to use the real certificate somehow from the server end as I dont need to decrypt any of the no header data.

I find the networking side of c# is not very well documented and a little all over the place.

Just for reference i can get the URI from the TcpClient using:

```
 IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)clientTcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

 IPAddress ipAddress = ipEndPoint.Address;

 // Get the hostname.
 IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
 String hostName = ipHostEntry.HostName;

 // Get the port.
 Int32 port = ipEndPoint.Port;
```

But not the requested page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the target hostname might be visible in the TLS handshake as SNI extension or by analyzing the certificate returned by the server **the path component of the URL is only contained in the HTTP request**. Since this HTTP request is only done after TLS handshake and the request is thus already encrypted **you cannot get to the full path without decrypting the request**. This means that blocking access to a specific path is not possible without SSL man in the middle and thus requires a certificate for the target site owned by the man in the middle and trusted by the client.

Not that this is true for CONNECT requests too since these requests only contain the target hostname but the path component is again only contained in the encrypted HTTP request sent inside the tunnel created by CONNECT.